# atomic transaction not working - ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I am trying to achieve atomicitiy in while doing my saves (which are essentially updates on each rows).

```
params[:player_types].each do |p_type_params|
  if p_type_params[:id]
    player = @player_types.find(p_type_params[:id])
    player.assign_attributes(p_type_params)
    @player_types << player
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @player_types.each do |player_type|
    if player_type.save
      "DO Something.."
    else
      "DO something else.."
      errors = true
    end
  end
end
```

Inspite of saving withing the transaction block, I can see partial saves also i.e. one of the rows get updated and the erroneous one does not (obviously) where as I would have wanted the updated row to be rolled back since there was atleast one row that could not be updated due to an error. Is my interpretation of transaction block correct in this case? How do I achieve an atomic save in my case?

EDIT: The model validates for uniqueness of one of the columns, which would be the reason for failing to update in the Database at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise an error inside your transaction block to abort the transaction; setting `errors` doesn't impact the transaction.

For instance:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @player_types.each do |player_type|
    if player_type.save
      "DO Something.."
    else
      "DO something else.."
      raise "save failed!"
    end
  end
end
```

The more conventional way of doing this, of course, is to use `save!` which raises an exception for you when it fails:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @player_types.each do |player_type|
    player_type.save!
  end
end
```

If you really need to "DO Something" on failure (besides aborting the transaction), you'll have to use the first method.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This does make sense, I will try it shortly !!

Comment: In the second method, will just save! suffice, or should it be `@player_types.save`

Comment: Good catch! It should actually be `player_type.save!`. Fixed above.

Comment: Also, if you want to get fancy, you can shorten the middle three lines to `@player_types.each(&:save!)`

Comment: For some reason, it still is not reflecting. I just did exactly as the second method, it takes me to the validation error but when redirect back to the page, the one of the field has been updated. Should I also do some resuce or enclose the transaction between begin and end?

Comment: You should find that nothing has been changed in the database if any one of the `save!` calls fails. But your _in memory objects_ don't revert back to their previous state unless you call `reload` on them. My guess is that what you are seeing is a rendering of those in memory objects. If you can't work that out, please post a separate question -- you'll need to show more of your (controller) code.

Comment: Actually no, its even reflected in the database. Also I see this when I redirect to the page (and not render). is there something more that I need to show here? Edit: the model is made to fail for "Validation failed"